# Expected Value of Maximum of Two Lognormal Random Variables with One Source of Randomness

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

We have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are log normally distributed, with suitable parameters, what is the expected value for $\max(X,Y)$?

Given,

$$
X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z};\quad Y=e^{\nu+\tau Z};\quad Z\sim N(0,1)
$$

We need to find an expression for $$E[\text{max}(X,Y)]$$

$X,Y$ are independent drawings.

Please note I have reached the step below, but am unsure how to proceed further.

## Steps Tried

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\max\left(X,Y\right)\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{Y}\left(x\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}yf_{X}\left(y\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)dy
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{Y}\left(x\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)dx{\displaystyle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)dx
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\tau}\phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)dx\quad\text{, Substitution }u=\left(\frac{\ln x-\nu}{\tau}\right)\Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x\tau}dx
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u\tau+\nu}\phi\left(u\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{u\tau+\nu-\mu}{\sigma}\right)du
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\displaystyle =e^{\nu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u\tau}\phi\left(u\right)}\Phi\left(\frac{u\tau+\nu-\mu}{\sigma}\right)du
\end{eqnarray*}

## Related Question

Please note, this present question was mis-phrased due to my limited knowledge; but still provides an interesting and instructive solution. The more general case has been made into a new question:

[Expected Value of Maximum of Two Lognormal Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614050/expected-value-of-maximum-of-two-lognormal-random-variables)

Comment: $Z = \max(X,Y)$. if $X,Y$ are independent :
$$P(Z \le a) = \int_0^a F_Y(x) F_X'(x) + F_X(x) F_Y'(x) dx = F_Y(a)F_X(a)$$
so that :
$$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_0^\infty 1-F_Y(x)F_X(x) dx$$ which shouldn't be easy to compute.

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for you suggestion. I partly understand it. Is there a x missing in the $$E(Z)$$  after the integral sign?

Comment: no, if $U$ has support $[0;b]$ then $\mathbb{E}[U] = \int_0^b x f_U(x) dx = b F(b) - \int_0^b F_U(x) dx = \int_0^b (1-F_U(x))dx$ (with $F_U'(x) = f_U(x)$ and integration by part). this stays true for infinite support random variable so that $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Z(x))dx$. finally with $F_Z(x) = P(Z \le x) = F_Y(x)F_X(x)$ you get my formula

Comment: @user1952009 Could you please clarify how you get $bF(b)=\int_{0}^{b}1dx$

Comment: Given the way you have defined the problem, i.e. $$
X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z};\quad Y=e^{\nu+\tau Z};\quad Z\sim N(0,1)$$ you only have 1 random variable $Z$, not two.  Do you mean that you have two independent drawings of $Z$, because that is not what is described?

Comment: @wolfies yes Thanks for pointing this out. Please note, my level of understanding is very basic at best. What would be the standard way to represent two log normal distrbutions that are independent... ? Would independent drawings from $Z$ be good enough for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma = \tau$, then 
\begin{align*}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= E\left(e^{\sigma Z} \max\big(e^{\mu}, e^{\nu}\big) \right)\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\max\big(e^{\mu}, e^{\nu}\big).
\end{align*}

WLOG, we assume that $\sigma < \tau$ below. Let $\lambda = \frac{\mu-\nu}{\tau-\sigma}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
E(\max(X, Y)) &= E\left(\mathbb{I}_{Z \le \lambda} X + \mathbb{I}_{Z > \lambda} Y\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda} e^{\mu+\sigma x - \frac{1}{2}x^2} dx +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\lambda}^{\infty} e^{\nu+\tau x - \frac{1}{2}x^2} dx.
\end{align*}
The remaining is now routine calculus.

Comment: Awesome answer. Much appreciated. Please note, given my limited understanding of these concepts. Is the definition I have used for the two random variables, $X,Y$ the standard way to define two independent log normal random variables. I suppose your answer would change if this were not so.

Comment: No. Your definition is not for independent log normal random variables, and the answer will change correspondingly.

Comment: Pardon my mistake … Could you please suggest the proper way to define two independent random variables and their expected maximum value accordingly.

Comment: You can assume that $X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z_1}$ and $Y=e^{\nu+\tau Z_2}$, where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent. This will be another question.

Comment: Thanks I will phrase this as a new question … I will accept this one since it is still a very useful technique you have illustrated. The new question is here and any suggestions you have would be much appreciated as always. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614050/expected-value-of-maximum-of-two-lognormal-random-variables